# Bibliography cannot be created (plain.bst not found)

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio

Since my bibliography wasn't working, I created a test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Test}
\author{test}
\date{February 2020}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.
There is another theory which states that this has already happened.


\section{Conclusion}
``I always thought something was fundamentally wrong with the universe''\cite{adams1995hitchhiker}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

with the corresponding bib file `references.bib` as

```
@book{adams1995hitchhiker,
  title={The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  author={Adams, D.},
  isbn={9781417642595},
  url={http://books.google.com/books?id=W-xMPgAACAAJ},
  year={1995},
  publisher={San Val}
}
```

in the same folder. If I execute this in Overleaf, it works fine. However, in TeXstudio I get the following error message

```
|Process started: bibtex "QuellenTest".aux

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: QuellenTest.aux
I couldn't open style file plain.bst
---line 3 of file QuellenTest.aux
 : \bibstyle{plain
 :                }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I couldn't open database file references.bib
---line 4 of file QuellenTest.aux
 : \bibdata{references
 :                    }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file QuellenTest.aux
I found no style file---while reading file QuellenTest.aux
(There were 4 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)"
```

I have then downloaded a `plain.bst` file and put it in the same folder, but it still produces the same error.

Comment: That is a very old latex installation. Debian is known to split up texlive into many smaller Debian packages. Are you sure you have installed enough for that texlive to support bibtex? Secondly plain is not compilable with natbib, you need plainnat

Comment: @daleif
No, I am not sure. Do you think it is worth it to update this manually or should I just reinstall TexStudio entirely to make sure everything is included and up to date?
Thanks for the tip, that's just one of the leftovers from trying some different commands to see where the problem starts.

Comment: Texstudio has nothing to do with it. It just calls pdflatex, bibtex etc for you. Get a newer larex installation